# Product of disjoint cycles in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$. Show that if $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint cycles of lengths $l_1,...,l_r$, then so is $\tau \cdot \sigma \cdot \tau^{-1}\\\\\\$.

Is it correct to do it in this way:

Suppose $\sigma = (a_1...a_{l_1}) \cdot ... \cdot (x_1...x_{l_r})$ where all cycles are disjoint, then

$\tau \cdot \sigma \cdot \tau^{-1} = \tau \cdot (a_1...a_{l_1}) \cdot ... \cdot (x_1...x_{l_r}) \cdot \tau^{-1} = \tau \cdot (a_1...a_{l_1}) \cdot e \cdot ... \cdot e \cdot (x_1...x_{l_r}) \cdot \tau^{-1} = \\\tau \cdot (a_1...a_{l_1}) \cdot \tau^{-1} \cdot \tau  \cdot ... \cdot \tau^{-1} \cdot \tau \cdot (x_1...x_{l_r}) \cdot \tau^{-1} =\\
 (\tau \cdot (a_1...a_{l_1}) \cdot \tau^{-1}) \cdot \tau  \cdot ... \cdot \tau^{-1} \cdot (\tau \cdot (x_1...x_{l_r}) \cdot \tau^{-1}) = \\
(\tau(a_1) ...\tau(a_{l_1})) \cdot ...\cdot(\tau(x_1) ...\tau(x_{l_r}))\\$

$\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ are bijections, therefore cycles $(\tau(a_1) ...\tau(a_{l_1})), ... ,(\tau(x_1) ...\tau(x_{l_r}))$ are disjoint with lengths $l_1, ..., l_r$ respectively, as cycles $(a_1...a_{l_1}), ...  ,(x_1...x_{l_r})$ are disjoint.

Comment: It is indeed correct, but a bit long.

Comment: You actually need the bijectivity of $\tau$ to know that $(\tau(a_1) ...\tau(a_{l_1}))$ actually is a single cycle - you write it as one but that needs proof. So I think your proof is a bit short.